# SQL : Finding nearest point within different radius from given latitude & longitude

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

So far I've been able to find the nearest point (warehouse in this context) within the same radius. (common question with lot of answers already).

**This is the actual code (it does not use multiple radius)**

```
$radius = 5; // miles

$q = "
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      warehouse_latitude.post_id,
      warehouse_longitude.meta_value as longitude,
      warehouse_latitude.meta_value as latitude,
      ((ACOS(SIN($latitude * PI() / 180) * SIN(warehouse_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) + COS($latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(warehouse_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) * COS(($longitude - warehouse_longitude.meta_value) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance
    FROM {$this->wpdb->postmeta} as warehouse_latitude
      LEFT JOIN {$this->wpdb->postmeta} as warehouse_longitude ON warehouse_latitude.post_id = warehouse_longitude.post_id 
    WHERE warehouse_latitude.meta_key = 'warehouse_latitude' AND warehouse_longitude.meta_key = 'warehouse_longitude'
    HAVING distance < $radius
    ORDER BY distance ASC
    LIMIT 1
";
```

**Instead :**

I'd like to select the nearest point but **radius is defined for each point** (warehouse).

- Point A (9714) : 5 miles radius
- Point B (9715) : 2 miles radius
- Point C (9716) : 10 miles radius

So if point B and C are in range and point B is the closest, it should select point B.

**wp_postmeta table:**

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key             | meta_value
------------------------------------------------------
324802  | 9714    | warehouse_latitude   | 47.1978754
324809  | 9715    | warehouse_latitude   | 47.2064462
324814  | 9716    | warehouse_latitude   | 47.214434
324803  | 9714    | warehouse_longitude  | -1.54441
324810  | 9715    | warehouse_longitude  | -1.5461347
324815  | 9716    | warehouse_longitude  | -1.565993
324806  | 9714    | warehouse_radius     | 5
324811  | 9715    | warehouse_radius     | 2
324816  | 9716    | warehouse_radius     | 10
```

**Schema:**

[image]

Comment: Can you add sample data in the form of a table, and then show the expected output?  This is a standard Haversine MySQL query, but I don't see exactly what you want here.

Comment: `Left join x... where x=...` is the same as `inner join x`. So instead, move the condition to the on clause. Also, what's wrong with radians?

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: @Strawberry sure, i don't mind using radians, this was the first solution i found.

Comment: @SalmanA any problem with that? It would work without the LIMIT but well i only need to get one :).

Comment: @Brieuc sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Exterminator this issue is that i select the nearest point using only one radius (distance < $radius) and i would like to have different radius for each point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here the solution (updated from the previous query).

Do not mind to give another anwser if you have a more efficient/readable way to calculate the distance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  warehouse_latitude.post_id,
  warehouse_longitude.meta_value as longitude,
  warehouse_latitude.meta_value as latitude,
  warehouse_radius.meta_value as radius,
  ((ACOS(SIN($latitude * PI() / 180) * SIN(warehouse_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) + COS($latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(warehouse_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) * COS(($longitude - warehouse_longitude.meta_value) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance
FROM {$this->wpdb->postmeta} as warehouse_latitude
  LEFT JOIN {$this->wpdb->postmeta} as warehouse_longitude ON warehouse_latitude.post_id = warehouse_longitude.post_id
  LEFT JOIN {$this->wpdb->postmeta} as warehouse_radius ON warehouse_latitude.post_id = warehouse_radius.post_id 
WHERE warehouse_latitude.meta_key = 'warehouse_latitude' AND warehouse_longitude.meta_key = 'warehouse_longitude' AND warehouse_radius.meta_key = 'warehouse_radius'
HAVING distance < (radius * 0.62)
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I added a join on the radius values:

```
LEFT JOIN {$this->wpdb->postmeta} as warehouse_radius ON warehouse_latitude.post_id = warehouse_radius.post_id
```

And another condition in WHERE statement:

```
AND warehouse_radius.meta_key = 'warehouse_radius'
```

Therefore:

I can update the HAVING statement to:

```
HAVING distance < (radius * 0.62) -- Km to Miles
```

Comment: Try using `HAVING distance < (warehouse_radius.radius * 0.62)`

Comment: Sure i can do that. I actually do use this alias in the returned response (since i might use it later on ;). Same same.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

```
1  LEFT JOIN warehouse_longitude ON ... -- This is an INNER JOIN because of LINE 3
2  LEFT JOIN warehouse_radius ON ...    -- This is also an INNER JOIN, because of LINE 4 
3 WHERE warehouse_longitude.meta_key = 'warehouse_longitude' 
4   AND warehouse_radius.meta_key = 'warehouse_radius'
```

So you might as well write these as INNER JOINs to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll try it and update my answer :).